# Php parsing of specific lines

Tags: php, facebook, parsing

```
 Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Sujay John
                [id] => 765972231
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Bhawesh Kumar
                [id] => 820284831
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Deepak Sharma
                [id] => 1054741730
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => Raman Steta
                [id] => 1093844232
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => Rohit Sharma
                [id] => 1101853912
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [name] => Rakesh Sharma
                [id] => 1128223845
            )
```

I want the output like:

```
name= Sujay John
id= 765972231

[name] => Deepak Sharma
[id] => 1054741730
```

like that....only name and id of the user.

Comment: i can't figure out the code. Using graph api i have dumped all the code into a raw file but can't figure out how to extract usefull information from file dump and store that content in database

Comment: @KshitijSood http://php.net/arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($level01['data'] as $dataArray){
   echo 'name='.$dataArray['name'].' id='.$dataArray['id'].;
}
```

hope that helps or I got the question wrong...